# How to check if safeTransferFrom succeeded?

Tags: solidity, transactions, tokens, transfer, transferfrom

`safeTransferFrom` function doesn't return any value:

```
function safeTransferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 tokenId
) public virtual override {
    safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
}
```

How can I check that it worked correctly before proceeding with another task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By listening to `Transfer(from, to, tokenId)` event.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-Transfer-address-address-uint256-

Or

```
contract.safeTransferFrom(params
  .then(transaction => {
    console.log(`Transaction hash: ${transaction.hash}`);
    return transaction.wait();
  })
  .then(receipt => {
    console.log(`Transaction mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
``
```